# Using Android Google Play Dev API from Android app

Tags: java, android, google-play-developer-api

I would like to implement the Google Dev API within an android app.
I am trying to use the samples provided by Google for Java, here:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-publisher-api/tree/master/v3/java/src/com/google/play/developerapi/samples

I just modified them to provide the InputStream of the client-secret.json file using the AssetManager of Android.

Yet, this is still not really compatible with Android, because of java.awt dependencies as it looks like in the error below:

```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:354)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/awt/Desktop;
    at com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.browse(AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.java:129)
    at com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.onAuthorization(AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.authorize(AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.java:81)
    at net.myapp.AndroidPublisherHelper.authorizeWithInstalledApplication(AndroidPublisherHelper.java:140)
```

For the record, the code around line 140 is :

```
    return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
            flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize(INST_APP_USER_ID);
```

which involves the dependencies:

```
 import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
 import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
```

How can I convert this samples to make them compatible with Android. I have no clue how they work so I am just copy/pasting this in an AsyncTask that is supposed to establish the connection and list my dev apks.

Answer (score 1):

You must logging in through the play-services-auth library.

This code sample may help you:

```
private void requestSignIn( final Context context ) {
    GoogleSignInOptions signInOptions =
            new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                    .requestEmail()
                    .requestScopes(new Scope( AndroidPublisherScopes.ANDROIDPUBLISHER ))
                    .build();
    GoogleSignInClient client = GoogleSignIn.getClient( context, signInOptions );

    // The result of the sign-in Intent is handled in onActivityResult.
    startActivityForResult(client.getSignInIntent(), REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN);
}

    @Override
protected void onActivityResult( int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data ) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN:
            if ( resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED ) {
                // TODO: login permitted
                break;
            }
            if ( resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null ) {
                handleSignInResult( data );
            }
            break;
    }
    super.onActivityResult( requestCode, resultCode, data );
}

private void handleSignInResult( Intent result ) {
    GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(result)
            .addOnSuccessListener( googleAccount -> {
                Log.d("Log", "Signed in as " + googleAccount.getEmail() );

                // Use the authenticated account to sign in to the Drive service.
                GoogleAccountCredential credential =
                        GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                                this, Collections.singleton( AndroidPublisherScopes.ANDROIDPUBLISHER ));
                credential.setSelectedAccount(googleAccount.getAccount());
                new BackgroundTask().execute( credential );
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(exception -> {
                Log.e( "Log", "Unable to sign in.", exception);
            });
}

class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<GoogleAccountCredential, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground( GoogleAccountCredential... googleAccountCredentials ) {
        main( googleAccountCredentials[0] );
        return null;
    }
}


// Vars from AndroidPublisherHelper

public static void main( GoogleAccountCredential credential) {
    Preconditions.checkArgument(!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(ApplicationConfig.PACKAGE_NAME),
        "applicationName cannot be null or empty!");

    credential.setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff());


    // Set up and return API client. Create the API service.
    final AndroidPublisher service = new AndroidPublisher.Builder(
        newTrustedTransport(), JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(ApplicationConfig.APPLICATION_NAME)
        .build();

    final Edits edits = service.edits();

    // Create a new edit to make changes.
    Insert editRequest = edits
            .insert( ApplicationConfig.PACKAGE_NAME, // Or other app's package id
                    null /** no content */);
    AppEdit appEdit = editRequest.execute();

    // Do what you want with appEdit according to the API
    //.....
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**WARNING!**

I suppose that publishing your application containing this library violates Google Play policy through the following scenarios (described by links below):

> Do not allow third parties to use the APIs to publish to your account on your behalf. Do not use the APIs to offer a developer service or tool which creates, uploads, publishes, distributes or updates apps to the Google Play Store. Doing this is a violation of the Google Play Developer API Terms of Service. Such actions may result in your account being suspended, and your apps removed from the Google Play Store. Everything done on your account is your responsibility, and allowing a third party to use your account puts all of your users at risk.

and terms:

> Publishing API: You will only use the Publishing API for your own activities related to your distribution of products under the Google Play Developer Distribution Agreement. **You will not utilize a third party's Developer Account to access the Publishing API, use the Publishing API to publish apps on behalf of a third party through a developer tool or service, or share your own Developer Account to allow a third party to access the Publishing API on your behalf.** A violation of this provision may result in suspension, termination of access to the Publishing API, your Developer Account, and/or suspension or termination of third-party apps created, uploaded, published, distributed or updated in violation of this provision.

See links:
https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api_usage 
https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/terms